# Is there any way that multiple users can upload to my Youtube channel via Youtube-api

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have used the Youtube-api and also created the oauth-clientId for some demo project. I also used the Client libraries (java & javascript) for uploading videos to my channel and i succeeded. But i don't want to share my login credentials and want my client users to upload videos to my channel. Is there any way, i mean documentation or procedure or youtube-implementations?

Comment: nope. I used the javascript client library code to upload the video. When i ran the code. It asked me to login for authorization and i logged in and then the code was able to access my channel where i then upload the video. If other user logs in then video is uploaded to  his/her channel. @Archer

Comment: Have your credentials stored on the server. Let the user send a file to the server which will then make the call to the youtube api.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks - I wasn't aware of that.  Comment deleted.

Comment: There's no way to really do this securely, without having some server side code to help it along. The problem is that if you could upload videos simply using an API code from client side, then anyone could use that code at any time to upload anything in your name. Server side code would provide you the ability to have some filtration control over it.

Comment: @JonasGiuro suppose, if i want to do it via users browser and not include server thing in between.

Comment: @TahirHussainMir you cant do this client sided the only way to do this will be server sided.

Comment: @TahirHussainMir If it were possible, you would be forfeiting control of your YouTube account over to the public, which afaik is against YouTube's ToS.

Comment: @Shea Ah! Yeah. So, that means backend has to play the required role.

Comment: @TahirHussainMir Yes, exactly.

Comment: @JonasGiuro You said, store credentials on server. But how could i authenticate myself on server in case of google authentication??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Java as you said.  You should have a refresh token after your application has been authenticated.

The refresh token can be used to request a new access token.  You should use this refresh token to allow others to upload to your channel.  Note: To my knowledge you cant get a refresh token with the JavaScript client library due to security issues. You need to use a server sided language to do this.

**For Refrence:**

YouTube does not support service accounts so that wont work.  API Key is only used for accessing public data so that wont work either.

Comment: what in case of javascript. You mean i have to save that refresh token and then let them upload. And what if the token was expired?

Comment: I mean that authentication with Client sided languages does not return a refresh token.   So if your access token expires you will personally need to authenticate it again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will have a look at it. ^_^ @DalmTo

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer to my question and now my users[whom i give some authorizations] can directly upload to my youtube channel. 
As per the comments i received for my question, i came to the conclusion that i have to do it at the server side because of the security issues.

The thing which came to rescue is namely `Refresh Token`.
I first created a simple application through which i logged & uploaded video [uploading is not necessary] into my youtube account and received the respected `refresh token`

Then i saved that refresh token through which i created a `Credential` object manually.

You can check the code provided by google :

### UploadVideo.java

```
Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "uploadvideo");
```

This is what i replaced with [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords_axis/src/main/java/adwords/axis/auth/GetRefreshToken.java) and obtained my own refresh token.
*Refresh token does not expire like normal access token, and is used to generate normal access token when needed. So, refresh token was the key to my question*

Then at the backend, the only thing you have to do is just create the `Credential` manually. You can use this code

```
getCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
.setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
.setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
.build()
.setRefreshToken(refreshToken)
// The refresh token here will be the same you received offline.
```

**Here is the official google doc about this concept**

> Refreshing an access token (offline access)
>
> Access tokens periodically expire. You can refresh an access token without prompting the user for permission (including when the user is not present) if you requested offline access to the scopes associated with the token.
>
> If you use a Google API Client Library, the client object refreshes the access token as needed as long as you configure that object for offline access.
>      If you are not using a client library, you need to set the access_type HTTP query parameter to offline when redirecting the user to Google's OAuth 2.0 server. In that case, Google's authorization server returns a refresh token when you exchange an authorization code for an access token. Then, if the access token expires (or at any other time), you can use a refresh token to obtain a new access token.
>
> Requesting offline access is a requirement for any application that needs to access a Google API when the user is not present. For example, an app that performs backup services or executes actions at predetermined times needs to be able to refresh its access token when the user is not present. The default style of access is called online.
>
> Server-side web applications, installed applications, and devices all obtain refresh tokens during the authorization process. Refresh tokens are not typically used in client-side (JavaScript) web applications.